# How to divide <p> inside the <div> into a box of 2 rows 2 columns using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to divide the paragraphs into 4 parts (2 rows, 2 cols) inside the div mid-box using flexbox.

Got no idea how to even proceed.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

```
<div class="mid-box"> 
<p><strong>Learn</strong>Get the facts about this issue and how we're helping.</p>
<p><strong>Volunteer</strong>Find out about upcoming events that need your help.</p>
<p><strong>Share</strong>Let your social media networks know about this important cause.</p>
<p><strong>Donate</strong>Help us raise money to make a big difference with this issue.</p>
</div>
```

I want to divide and align

tags as follows -

```
| Learn | Volunteer |
|-------------------|
| Share | Donate    |
```

Comment: This isn't a place to hope for code without trying to write your own. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Well, I understand your concern. The thing is that I can do this by putting every two of them into sub-container and then apply flex-direction: row to 1st and 2nd sub-box and then flex-direction: column to mid-box but that's not what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use for parent element `flex-wrap: wrap;` and for child elements `flex-basis: 50%` properties.

Result

```css
.mid-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

p:nth-child(1) {
  background: orange;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightblue;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightcoral;
}

p:nth-child(4) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="mid-box">
  <p><strong>Learn</strong>Get the facts about this issue and how we're helping.</p>
  <p><strong>Volunteer</strong>Find out about upcoming events that need your help.</p>
  <p><strong>Share</strong>Let your social media networks know about this important cause.</p>
  <p><strong>Donate</strong>Help us raise money to make a big difference with this issue.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Though, I did it by the method I'd mentioned above in a comment but this definetly solved my proble, thanks.